# For loop for mean value?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

How to code for loop to generate mean values of data form structure ?

```
 m1=mean(x1.data);
 m2=mean(x2.data);
 m3=mean(x3.data);
 m4=mean(x4.data);
 mi=mean(xi.data);
```

Comment: If you stored all of your x structures in an array you could access them as `x[i].data` and then you'd be able to do it in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use different variable names (instead of an array), you can use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). It's not considered good practice though:

```
for n=1:10
  eval(['m' num2str(n) '=mean(x' num2str(n) '.data);']);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [mean](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mean.html). You can specify the dimensions.

Comment: But the OP is using structs with different names... so how does specifying dimensions help here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```
structfun(@mean, x1)
```

assuming you do as other Dan has suggested and made `x` and array of structs instead of having many separately named variables.